# Given $f(x)=\arctan(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ and $g(x)=\arctan(x)$ find their constant summand

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives

Show that this  functions differ in constant summand $f(x)=\arctan(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ and $g(x)=\arctan(x)$  in $(-\infty;1)$ and $(1;\infty)$ Answer is for $(-\infty;1)$ $\pi/4$ and for $(1;\infty)$ is $\frac{-3\pi}{4}$. I am at differential in my class.

I know that $\arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ but don't know how to use to obtain this.

Comment: $\tan (A+B)=\frac {\tan A+\tan B} {1-\tan A \tan B}$. Put $A=\frac {\pi} 4$ and $B=g(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle h( x) =f( x) -g( x)$. Domain of $\displaystyle h$ is $\displaystyle \mathbb{R} -\{1\}$. Derivatives of $\displaystyle f$ and $\displaystyle g$ are respectively:
\begin{gather}
f'( x) =\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{2}}\frac{( 1-x) -( -1)( 1+x)}{( 1-x)^{2}} =\frac{1}{\left( 1+x^{2}\right)} \tag{1}\\
 \notag\\
g'( x) =\frac{1}{1+x^{2}} \tag{2}
\end{gather}
Therefore, $\displaystyle h'( x) =f'( x) -g'( x) =0$ for all $\displaystyle x\in Domain\ ( h)$

What does this say about $\displaystyle h( x)$?

Fix any $\displaystyle x >1$ and take any $\displaystyle y >x$. Now by LMVT on $\displaystyle [ x,y]$, there exists $\displaystyle \theta _{y} \in ( x,y) \ $such that we get:
\begin{gather}
\frac{h( y) -h( x)}{y-x} =h'( \theta _{y}) =0 \notag\\
\Longrightarrow h( y) =h( x) \tag{3}
\end{gather}
In $\displaystyle ( 3) :$ Taking limit $\displaystyle y\rightarrow \infty $ on both sides to get
\begin{equation*}
h( x) =\lim _{y\rightarrow \infty } h( y) =-\frac{\pi }{4} -\frac{\pi }{2} =-\frac{3\pi }{4}
\end{equation*}
Therefore on $\displaystyle ( 1,\infty ) ,\ h( x) =-\frac{3\pi }{4}$.

I leave it onto you to use similar arguments as above for the second part.

Comment: Thank you very much for very detailed answer!.